# Regex reference and its fate

Tags: discussion

### Background

I was whining about the fact that [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag suffers from bad quality questions and answers. I did something about it. I rampaged through the review queue:

[image: regex review almost done]

But I wasn't satisfied. I noticed high-rep users (3k+) answering such obvious questions.

Now there are two types of questions I noticed:

- Questions that are clear duplicates, but you can't find one quickly.
- Questions that ask about explaining a regex and end up with some copy-paste from an [automated script](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) or something similar.

Every time you try to discuss the matters with those answerers they always come up with the following arguments:

- "*I'm just trying to help.*"
- "*I don't know a duplicate.*"
- "*It's fine to answer `give me ze code` questions.*" <sup>did I make this up?</sup>

Now let's be honest, in the long run you aren't helping anyone with a low-quality answer (without explanation) like "*this regex does the job: `fancy regex here`*".

So I was wondering, there should be a solution: a reference!

### Situation

So after some hesitation and time I really started in creating [this reference](https://gist.github.com/Hamz-a/1662d09db09156e8b2b0). I asked on how I should approach it in chat rooms, etc. I got great feedback. Today I posted it [**as a question on Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618).

Now as expected there is always a set of people who are against this kind of reference. The question is: **what should be the fate of this reference?**

- Closed?
- Deleted? (I don't really mind if it gets closed, but please don't delete it.)
- Two people <sup>([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean#comment35029364_22937618) and  [2](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15730341#15730341))</sup> suggested to split it up in a Q&A: A general question in the form "What is a regex?" and the answer with "the list". I like this idea, but before doing anything, I thought lets ask on Meta Stack Overflow before people would think I'm acting on my own.

For all those who are against it, please don't tell me "according to the rules this should be closed". Yes, I do respect the rules, but sometimes they need to be broken. See:

- [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
- [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Also, try to come up with a (semi-)solution to:

- [Regex - don't feed them - teach them how to fish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214238/regex-dont-feed-them-teach-them-how-to-fish)
- [Quality problems in regex answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102756/quality-problems-in-regex-answers)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188408/why-arent-these-give-me-teh-regexz-questions-closed

### Some comments on comments

> Why is this a question? This is a (very good) blog post. If this has to be on Stack Overflow it should be in the tag wiki for regex.

I wrote it to solve a problem like described above. There's a lot of blog posts about regex on the Internet. If I ever wrote one, it should be an advanced one. It's not in the tag wiki since:

1. We won't be able to close as duplicate
2. Have you ever seen someone read it?

> You should have at least asked on Meta Stack Overflow before doing something like this.

I didn't ask on Meta Stack Overflow, but I did ask in *Tavern on the Meta* chat room. Also on several other chatrooms like PHP, Regex, C++, etc. Most of them told me to just post the question and see what will happen. Someone told me it's redundant since there is [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info). Anyway, I did ask around.

> This is incredible. What about links to the obviously-great and official off-site resources? For instance, Sun's page on [greedy vs. reluctant vs. possessive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), and the Pattern JavaDocs?

I'm trying to make it as on-topic as possible.

> It's not a question.
> I know, try to come up with a (semi-)solution. At least I tried.

---

Comment: This is yet another FAQ.  How often have you seen people reading FAQs?  In fact, the questions in FAQs actually happen to be the most frequently asked questions on SO.

Comment: I must appreciate the energy and enthusiasm that went into the activity, but a monolithic document with a list of questions isn't very search engine friendly nor is it very helpful for common mortals.

Comment: This is now the "Regex-Fu FAQ Mega Wiki". IMHO, a link to it should be added to the description of the regex tag.

Comment: FYI we decided on [gaming.stackexchange](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7901) that these sort of "collection questions" are not allowed.

Comment: Is it possible to make HREF anchors in answers? This post would be more valuable if it were possible to link to a particular section, instead of linking to the FAQ and always having to say "look under XXX section which is about halfway down..."

Comment: @BlueRaja I respect that decision. I think you can't compare these two problems. I mean just look at the accepted answer, it says `This is a Q&A site. This is not GameFAQs. This is not a wiki. Our job is not to collect and reorganize data. Our job is simply to answer the questions that we are asked.` while this is true and certainly logical for a [tag that has ~160 questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/candy-box-2) it's not really comparable to a [tag that has 85K](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) questions. We need a reference.

Comment: Btw I think it will be around the 100K, some people tend to not tag it as regex but do tag it with regex functions. Just take a look for php/regex related questions, already [6K questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-replace+or+preg-match+or+preg-match-all+or+preg-split+or+preg-replace-callback+-regex) added to 85K.

Comment: @aliteralmind That would be awesome, although I think that's currently impossible

Comment: Another option that you probably looked at already, split it into a bunch of regex question, every heading that you added in the answer. It's a lot of questions but you can always add more and it will be much more searchable in Google, which is what people normally use, because currently the reference questions don't pop up in the search results.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: Actually, that gives me an idea! If the admins would allow me to split the sections into separate answers, it would *exactly* fit the bill. You could provide a link to just the needed section.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: With your permission, I'd like to split the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) by placing each major section into a different answer. That way, instead of having to say "please look in XXX section which is about XXX down", users can be linked directly to the appropriate spot.

Comment: Actually, more than that, it can be given internal navigation, and a table of contents "master" answer. It's large and important enough that I think it's worthy of being broken up in this way.

Comment: @aliteralmind: Wiki lock works on one answer only.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Okay. So what about leaving HamZa's question as is, but creating one new wiki question per section? The original question remains the "main" one and will be "the" FAQ. Its answer will contain the table of contents. All other questions will be a section with a link back to the "main" TOC. The question in the sub-sections can be basically the same (perhaps terser), with only a reference back to the original. I have it down to ten pretty substantial sections, which also gives it room to grow: http://pastebin.com/reZxcQmB. Thanks.

Comment: @aliteralmind: I'll give it some thought, but right now I'm leaning towards leaving it the way it is now.  The software is not designed for what you're asking for.  The answer is currently at 15,000 characters; there's room for 15,000 more (although brevity is the soul of wit).

Comment: Beautiful work. Thanks for taking the time and writing that answer!

Comment: To @RobertHarvey, or any admin this applies to: I'd like to ask your consideration one more time, to allow the regex FAQ to be split into one question per section (I'd choose one *answer* per section, but this conflicts with "[Wiki lock works on one answer only.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate#comment10358_252868)"). The [Community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/248661) is formatted similarly, although *each question* is in its own question-post.

Comment: In my opinion, the ability to link directly to the appropriate section would provide a great benefit to the regex FAQ. I don't expect your "no" from April to change, but I did want to give it one more try. Thank you.

Comment: Right or wrong I just want to commend you @HamZa for your wonderful effort into making things more organized, rather than just continue to pile more crap on top of old! Well done!

Comment: [example of fairly high rep user farming rep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947740/getting-version-digits-using-regex)

Comment: You created a mess with no value. If you think the next time "Hey, let's create a simple FAQ about a complex topic", then please don't do it!

Comment: @hek2mgl at least 500 people openly disagree with you, looking at the stars and votes on the reference. HamZa's regex reference is the first place I go for *any* question I ever have about regex syntax, and is vastly superior to any other source. It is not a mess (indeed, it's well-organised) and has value to a large number of people.

Comment: @MarkAmery Beginner-OPs which get a comment, "please check this first" mostly missing privileges to down-vote if that didn't helped them. (or they just don't care) If this is *your* only first resource for regular expressions, then you make your life harder than it should be, there are better resources out there. But the most important question: Did the amount of duplicate/low quality questions decreased in the regexp tag?  Please also read my answer, I've elaborated on my concerns.

Comment: @HamZa I'm trying to edit the FAQ and add a new method for matching nested brackets under "Advanced Regex Fu" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162099), but I'm constantly getting an error from StackOverflow saying "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted". This even happens if I try to make an edit with no changes. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @jaytea hey there, thanks for your nice input! I added it with no problems,
 [see edit #138](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22944075/revisions). Maybe something really did go wrong? I don't know :_) You can also ping me in the [regex chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I'll drop my $.02 here just for laughs.

Purists gonna hate, but the fact is that **there are tags that need these sort of reference questions**. [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) are such tags I know for sure.

Why? Because us, the regulars, are tired of seeing the same questions over and over. We are tired of looking for duplicates and even though we [tried making a good list of duplicates](http://room-11.github.io/canonical.html) if it's not dead simple, no one will use it properly.

As such, such easy to remember, easy to link, easy to close as duplicate against - canonical questions are a necessity. Because no one wants the regulars to lose their sanity and ragequit. Will the site roll and move forward? probably. But the dam will break, and no one will be there to even try and stop the ocean of low quality stuff.

---

My opinion about the reference? It should become more Q&A-like. Services like Google as well as readers classify content in the question and content in the answer differently.

Comment: Who wants to close as duplicates anyways?  Has anyone tried any analysis of the count of VTC by the top answerers in a given tag?

Comment: @devnull: Closing as duplicate is essential. It generates more traffic to the canonical, and helps people remember it better. Basically, it *brings more people to where good content is*, which is the point.

Comment: I understand that.  I essentially said that I find it rather common that the same person would answer the exact same problem multiple (numerous?) times but not VTC.  Even if the duplicate isn't difficult to find.

Comment: @devnull: Welcome to the [tag:php] tag! Where [some users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol) answer the exact same closable questions over and over and over and over again!

Comment: I know citing examples would be bad: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22926788/2235132 for a starter.

Comment: In [python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) too, you can find [somebody](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answering those.

Comment: @devnull: the Python tag community is building their own list, off-site, at http://sopython.com. And yes, I do vote to close dupes a-plenty.

Comment: I find closing duplicates very tedious: I spend 10 minutes looking for the best duplicate while I could answer the question in 2 minutes. By the time I find a duplicate, the question is answered anyway and often answers have a few upvotes. Also, the new question and answers are not bad content, they are just duplicates.

Comment: If people are asking the same question over and over then they are using the people on these sites as a search query, you add a request and a human processes it and provides an answer, because the bots suck at it. The solution? Make bots not suck at it.

Comment: @Timo You've looking at it wrong. Close as duplicate was originally made to prevent the frustrating "SEARCH! CLOSED!" Users often get on forums. We are not human search queries, that's not what I'm here for. Also, it isn't that the bots suck, those users have a startling inability to use a search engine or preform any sort of research.

Comment: @SecondRikudo What am I looking at wrong? As long as there is demand there will be supply, search engines fail at the supply. Prime example is children googling things for their parents. The solution is to improve the system, make the people who are unable to use search engines somehow find these answers. For example by improving the search while you are writing a question on SO and using many exact match question/answers.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: Search engines do not fail at the supply. Most people never bother with all of the oh-so-complicated search engine advanced gizmo thingamajig. That is not the search engine's fault, it's the user's fault. This conversation has left the topic for a bit. So let's end it here. If you really wish to continue the discussion, please come to the PHP chat room on Stack Overflow Chat.

Comment: does this answer change now that we have "documentation" ??

Comment: @rlemon It might. Although I'm still lacking the feature of "close as a duplicate of documentation entry", that canonicals have.

Comment: @rlemon: It was closed down. See *[Sunsetting Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217)*

Answer (score 26):

The best place for this kind of information is the Tag Wiki.  However, tag wikis have certain problems:

1. They don't have much visibility.
2. You can't make multiple pages or links (i.e. it's not a true Wiki)
3. You can't close repeatedly-asked basic questions as dupes of them.
4. You can't vet them (they have no voting system)

Most questions like this get downvoted and closed.  But that's because most questions like this *are not very good reference questions,* and let's face it: we do expect more from these reference questions than the pedestrian troubleshooting questions that fill the front page every day.

In short, most of the facilities that are available to us in questions and answers are absent from tag wikis.

Comment: Indeed. If Tag Wikis were more prominent, it would have been a good place to put such a reference. However, like I said in my answer, if it isn't useful and isn't dead simple, no one will use it. As it is now, a Tag Wiki is not better than our [php chatroom attempt](http://room-11.github.io/canonical.html).

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Tag wikis are a good place to put *lists of links,* which this reference mostly is.  Look at the Tag Wiki for PHP; it is excellent.

Comment: Fact is, I've been active in the PHP tag for over a year, I'%, and I've never read the PHP's tag wiki. I rest my case. If I don't read it (and I *am* a reader, I actually read the FAQ the day I joined!), you can't expect users to read it. Not to mention you can't natively close against the Tag Wiki.

Comment: You can close against the one of many canonical posts listed in the Tag Wiki.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Seeing this answer and your action on the actual question seems to be a contradiction. From this answer I get the feeling you disagree but the lock-message tells a different story. Can you elaborate on that? (I'm one of the off-line authors of the canonicial question so I might be biased)

Comment: @rene: The "Wiki lock" was created specifically for these kinds of posts.  It allows the community to maintain the answer, while preventing new answers from being posted.

Comment: Tag wikis don't make good close targets.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for locking the question and moving "the list" to the answer section.

Comment: @Emracool Why not ?

Comment: @HamZa Because you can't vote to close as a duplicate of a tag wiki :P

Comment: @Emracool oh lol I was confused. I read "tag wiki" as a locked wiki question.

Comment: Tag wikis would be like Wikipedia for school assignments. You don't cite Wikipedia, you use its sources. Same deal with a tag wiki, a gateway to the canonical questions, not as what duplicates are closed against. @emr

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not clear from your answer nor your comments whether you welcome this reference being in Q&A format? You've listed some limitations of the tag wiki pages, but then have stated that it *is* the correct place for a list of duplicates. Where do you stand on the matter exactly? I'm quite against the Q&A format, as you can see from my answer.

Comment: @Duncan: Given that tag wikis still possess the same limitations as they did when I first wrote this post, I'm still of the mind that they... still have the same limitations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, I get that. I'm not asking about your thoughts on those, I'm referring to whether this regex information belongs in a tag wiki or in a Q&A (as it currently is).

Comment: @Duncan: It's question and answer information.  It belongs in a question and answer, as do all other questions and answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, just wanted to check your position. My thoughts are different, as my answer explains. I just didn't quite understand your thoughts based on your answer.

Answer (score 18):

I was about to ask a similar question here because I have the impression that the quality of Stack Overflow dropped quite a bit in the last years. I have no numbers to prove my impression and my memories may actually trick me, but I strongly doubt that.

In the early years most of the questions on Stack Overflow were interesting problems and fun to research and solve. In the recent years more and more questions seem, at least to me, to ask for trivial things, ask for solving simple and very specific problems like a compiler error in a given code snippet, ask for code for a very specific problem and so on. It seems to me like more and more people want to learn coding and instead of reading the manual, a book or going through a tutorials, the first thing they do after installing the compiler is asking how to implement Hello World on Stack Overflow.

On the one hand I really want to help people solve their problems, on the other hand I can not  avoid the impression that they are just investing close to zero effort to solve their problems on their own. I just want to yell RTFM! at them. I never thought of Stack Overflow as a site to teach people coding but to help people to solve nontrivial problems. I see no value in answering trivial question which often means nothing more than quoting the relevant section from the language, library or API documentation.

This view has of course some obvious problems. What looks trivial to me, may be nontrivial for others. How I understand the scope of Stack Overflow is not necessarily how the community understands it or how it is intended. There is of course also always the temptation to answer simple questions for a few more points. And last but not least some people have already the feeling that Stack Overflow is not as welcoming to newbies as it should or could be and this will not improve by more aggressively rejecting trivial questions.

But in my opinion this is what we as a community really should do. People will not be happy when they just get told to read the manuals but I am convinced that in the long term it will be in their favor, in the favor of the whole programing community. Learning to read and understand manuals is an important skill. Learning to research and solve problems on your own is an important skill, too. Getting a solution on a silver plate ready for copy and paste does not make you any wiser.

In consequence I really like the idea to have a couple of questions with pointers to relevant questions and maybe even external resources. It just works without the need for any changes. Instead of having to find a specific duplicate you can just point to one of a few questions. There is probably a small risk that this gets out of control and we have to figure out when it is okay to refer to such a question and when a real answer is more appropriate, but we should be able to get this right. Maybe a new option like close because trivial would be a good idea, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: "*Maybe a new option like close because trivial would be a good idea*" that's the removed "too localized" option. I miss it too but it doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: +1 _"I just want to yell RTFM!"_ Me too. And with regard to regex, that manual is clearly: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!"). I often wonder how many of the "experts" who upvoted bobinc's popular (but worthless) neverparseHTMLwithregex answer haven't actually read it? Most I guess. RTFM!

Comment: *This view has of course some obvious problems. What looks trivial to me, may be nontrivial for others. How I understand the scope of Stack Overflow is not necessarily how the community understands it or how it is intended.* Yes! As a relative newcomer to SO (I've only been here for a little over a year), I get the sense that we've "run out of questions to ask." There are now 2 types of SO questions: those that are impossibly hard/library-specific and usually have 0 answers, and duplicates.

Comment: I feel like the intermediate programmers (people like me), who are newer to SO, can get value out of answering these duplicate questions, so I don't mind them. Of course, that doesn't solve the problem that the old-timers have, which is having to wade through all of the questions that they find "trivial."

Answer (score 10):

Here's a POV from someone who doesn't know Regex very well. My questions may be "poor quality" and they may not. But I certainly put a lot of time into them before asking for help here. Having the regex community vote to close my question as a duplicate and saying it's already answered in this "canonical" page is pretty much the same as saying "here's a regex book, go figure it out." Well, thanks for putting me onto the link, and I'll add it to the many resources I consult before asking questions.

In fact, I'll go a little further, since it seems I'm not doing enough to answer questions on my own. I'll refrain from asking any more regex questions, since, after all, all of the answers are on this page, and I don't want to put the regex community to the trouble of closing them and pointing me to it. Furthermore, since y'all put in all this effort, I want to help out as well.

I'd like to offer to spend a half hour a day going to as many regex questions as I can find and voting to close them as duplicates, since after all they're all answered here as well. If y'all want to take me up on that, please let me know.

Sound like a plan?

Seriously, I can understand the frustration that some people feel when people ask "give me ze code" type questions, but I think it's important to distinguish between lazy questions and questions that beginners put a lot of effort into only to have someone point out that a simple answer was staring them in the face. If you don't make that distinction, you're being lazy too.

Comment: Indeed, there is such a thing as a lazy close vote as well.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, great job on starting to produce a canonical list of reference questions. This is *really* useful.

However, I have quite a big problem with this... This should be in the tag wiki, not posted as a Q&A. You say in your question:

> [...] It's not in the tag wiki since:
>
> 1. We won't be able to close as duplicate
> 2. Have you ever seen someone read it?

We shouldn't **ever** be closing a question as a duplicate of this list of references. We should be using your helpful list to find **the most appropriate duplicate question**.

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075066/question-mark-in-regex-difference-between-pattern-compile-title#29075066) recently and it was closed as  a duplicate of this reference list. Admittedly it's a simple question (perhaps irritating to the regex tag regulars), but we aren't really helping the user by pointing them at a monster answer with 100+ links. We should use your list to find a duplicate, then close it to point at that one.

By having the information presented in Q&A format, this sort of behaviour is possible. 500+ questions are linked to this reference question already, which seems a real shame.

Tag wikis *are* known to the tag regulars and they are easier to find than one specific reference question. I agree that most users don't read them, but then again most users don't read *anything*. What's important is that the list of duplicates is maintained by the experts and easy to access for the experts.

Summary - great information and thanks a lot for compiling it. Just the wrong location.

Comment: You raised some good points, your answer does make sense. It has been almost a year since I wrote it. I realised that this isn't the "ideal" way of doing things, I was too frustrated at that time. The problem? We can't go back now or rather I'm not motivated at all to go ping mods around to change the situation.

Comment: @HamZa We could open a separate question to discuss a migration strategy. Clearly the first step is to add all that useful information to the regex tag wiki. The difficult step is what to do with the Q&A. It could be radically edited so that it becomes just a placeholder pointing at the regex tag wiki. Simply deleting it would leave a lot of dangling placeholders on the linked questions...

Comment: @Duncan: Well, if you want to keep it alive as a link to the tag-wiki so as not to rip apart duplicate-links, then all answers should be deleted and the question closed as too broad as well. That way, noone will be able to link anything more to it, and there's a chance to get them corrected one at a time.

Comment: Isn't the ***character limit*** in tag wikis a real problem (I think the PHP FAQ one was close to limit before someone destroyed it)? What is the character limit? Perhaps state some of this in the answer?

Answer (score -2):

The reason why a lot duplicate / low quality questions appear in the regular expression tag is that some people just don't want to learn regular expressions or read a manual or follow a tutorial. They just want to get the job done. Do you really think that such people, which don't want to read a manual, will go through all the links collected in that answer and check if their problem has been solved already? Assuming that is pretty naive. The still ongoing amount of bad questions in that tag proves that.

What beginners really need is a step by step course/tutorial, or a book etc. They need to learn it from the beginning. A quick search on Google retrieves tons of such resources. Take this one for example: https://regexone.com/

My idea is that such step-by-step tutorials should be part of SO.

Possible use cases I have in mind:

Once a user has completed such a step by step course ...

- (1) he/she will be allowed to ask questions in that tag
- (2) If (1) is a too hard restriction in your opinion, we could at least make it visible to other users if a particular OP has completed the step by step course and if not we might point him to that in the comments and possibly (3) close questions based on that.

Comment: Anything in particular that strikes you as bad?

Comment: @RadLexus I've elaborated on that.

Comment: The problem is, we can't close questions as duplicates of a book or another website.

Comment: @CodyGray If we go with my point (1), we wouldn't even need to close questions.

Comment: Who creates and administers these courses? Who maintains them and audits them for correctness? How does someone prove that they have completed it?  This seems like an incredible amount of complexity that deviates significantly from our core mission as a Q&A site.

Comment: Your linked tutorial (https://regexone.com/) is a perfectly good starting point for a beginner, but useless as a reference for people who understand the basics of regex syntax but want to look up some detail - both because it isn't structured in a way that lets you easily jump to the section about whatever syntax is of interest to you, and because there are significant topics (like possessive vs greedy vs reluctant modifiers) that aren't covered at all.

Comment: Your whole approach to this topic is symptomatic of an unfortunately common mindset among experienced answerers that sees our primary job as being shepherding and chastising beginners who haven't done enough work before asking here. You're failing to see the value in the reference because you (correctly) observe that it isn't a useful starting point for a beginner learning regex... but it isn't meant to be, and that doesn't prevent it from having huge value to people like me. As @CodyGray says, don't lose focus on the core mission - we're here to provide information, not to mentor beginners.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't understand the question. Who closes questions? Who writes documentation articles? The community?

Comment: It's going to be *a lot* of work to get a complete course going. Are you volunteering to create it? We didn't have to have a complete Q&A site going in order to start doing it. Same for documentation—most of it is *still* incomplete. Not to mention the obvious fact that the infrastructure for this doesn't exist, someone from Stack Overflow would have to build it. They've got their hands full with Documentation still. And in addition to what Mark says, you are also making the assumption that most programmers have a *desire* to learn regular expressions, which is also false.

Comment: @MarkAmery No. I just want to address the point of low quality or duplicate  (and low quality) questions. The whole discussion is about that or not? And yes, I think a little base knowledge might be required to participate in a community. And this could be teached and checked through a step by step tutorial. That's similar to other things in life. You can't drive without a drivers license but a drivers licence doesn't require you to be a race-driver. You can't study without some prior education, but you don't need to be a professor for that. And so on.

Comment: @CodyGray If SO gives me the opportunity, Yes, I would volunteer for tags I know something about. At the end it is of course a community work, like "SO-documentation". I mean who writes all that? And imo such step-by-step tutorials add more value than "SO-documentation", but that's a different discussion.