# Close as duplicate of tag wiki

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, tag-wiki

In "[Regex reference and its fate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate)", a reference question for the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) was proposed. Several people noted that a resource like this should really be in the tag wiki.  However, questions cannot be closed as duplicates of the wiki.

What if we allowed the wiki as a valid target for duplication?

Comment: Do people even know about the tag wikis? They're not terribly obvious; I don't see anything that would lead people to discovering their existence beyond reading meta or exploring buttons they have little reason to click.

Comment: Maybe this would make the tag wiki more obvious?

Answer (score 3):

It would be hard to come up with many use cases for this, since most tags will need more than one reference question.  The actual problem with implementing it, is that tag wikis don't have the same functionality as Q&A, like search.  So since incoming users couldn't search for it, they would end up creating the dupes anyway.

I do think there is some solution dealing with canonical and reference questions, and have proposed some stuff before on the issue.  I think they really need to figure something out along those lines to help out the 'close-as-dupe' or even dupe creation process.

Answer (score 2):

The current convention for this is to reserve the Tag Wiki as an index for Canonical/Reference Question links.  There is a limit on how large a tag wiki page can be; I believe it is the same as any other post (30,000 characters), so putting canonical answers into the tag wiki won't work.

For good examples of this practice in action, see the Tag wikis for [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: Nitpick: I don't see any canonical questions linked in the [tag:android] tag wiki. The [tag:c++] and [tag:c#] wiki are both very good examples, though.