# Custom Stack Exchange category for very business specific requests

Tags: discussion

I checked out these Meta's before: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe) and [Regex reference and its fate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate).

I was going through the regex category seeing this [Stuck on a regular expression in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803763/stuck-on-a-regular-expression-in-c-sharp).

I technically wouldn't flag/downvote because the person did make an effort AND the question is not that trivial. Judging by title, scenario and solution however this question is useful to one person and really just one person only.

A "too broad"-flag  says: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

- Nope, there are a couple of ways which can be considered correct, so by that definition not too broad

[Help Center Link for "OffTopic"-Flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

```
 a specific programming problem, or
 a software algorithm, or
 software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
 a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
```

For this matter "A specific problem" or "A practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" Would potentially fit to justify the question.

- yes a very business requirement related problem however - not technology related
- nope. not unique to software development but this very particular problem

Here is where I really need an answer:

**From what I thought when I began visiting Stack Overflow through I had the impression that Stack Overflow was about documenting generic questions (problems) and solutions to them with only as much business background to simplify understanding the background. Am I mistaken in this?**

Because unless I am mistaken there is plenty of questions in the regex tag which violate this consideration. I enjoy helping people with their problems if they made an effort, but I don't think helping them will help anyone else because there's just an endless pool of questions with duplicates because of it.

If you compare this to a question titled like "conditional lookahead regex within nested group" or something like that, you would see that while it suits a question, it will also enable unrelated visitors to find an answer to their potential question.

Unfortunately however with, at least most regex question, you might as well title them all "regex not working".

Is it intended to be like this? Is there a flag I am not aware of? Or wouldn't it make sense to add another forum for very business specific problems?

Comment: There used to be the 'Too localized' close reason for questions that were either too limited in scope to be useful to anybody except the person asking the question or were only useful for a specific period of time. That was scrapped as part of the changes to close reasons, though I couldn't tell you precisely why (though I'd guess it was used incorrectly considerably more often than it was used correctly).

Comment: The official stance is that questions must be useful for future visitors. But if someone has seriously tried all other things first, and just can't get their problem solved... I for one wouldn't mind if they posted on SO.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's unfortunate. I would have associated "too localized" with "too business specific" as well

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yeah, I don't mind either if its not just obviously homework. It just would be nice if it was a split section between SO and very specific business problems.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You are correct, it was removed because the majority of the time it was used, it was used correctly.  Different SO users interpreted it as meaning wildly different things from each other, and from what SE intended when creating the close reason.  People having their questions closed also struggled to understand what it meant and how to fix a question closed for that reason, so while SE felt, and still feels, that closing questions for that reason is important, the mechanism to try to accomplish that caused more harm than good.

Comment: [regex] was a problem well before the "Too localized" close reason was removed.  They really are "can somebody Google this for me" questions, with the significant hang-up that Google doesn't do a very good job indexing them.  Best way to deal with them is to add the tag to your Ignored Tags section of your profile preferences.

Comment: @HansPassant I would agree that most of the time it's "Can someone google this for me" or "I was told regex is good for this but i am too lazy to learn it, give teh codez plz", but not in all cases. I don't mind helping if it's a difficult one. But the hundreth variant of "how to capture a number in case of xx-0000 pattern" just feels like a waste

Comment: @Servy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815290/c-sharp-programming-assignment is quite annoying too. Noobs asking for help with questions their teacher gave them. What to flag that for? offtopic? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")" If you go through the profile you can see that she's a nurse who wants to be a programmer, asked a noob question before and probably will do only that - ask for help with homework

Answer (score 2):

The best one can possibly do for a "too specific" question is tear off the "too specific" part to only leave the core issue, and give it a googlable title for that core issue.

Then any further questions with the same core problem can be closed as a duplicate.

Since "the person did make an effort AND the question is not that trivial", this particular question is indeed not close-worthy and is probably worthy of that "canonization cleanup".