# Error when trying to edit a post with zero changes

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

I'm getting an error when trying to edit this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075

Even if I make **zero** changes, when I click "Save Edits" the page scrolls up to the text box and throws the error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" without even so much as showing me where the error *is*! See exhibit A:

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Note that when [I tried to introduce an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate#comment531284_252868), I succeeded. So maybe it has something to do with reputation?

Comment: You do face all the normal editor restrictions and checks till you earn edit privileges on the site

Comment: @SurajRao The error suggests I have a mistake in formatting, not that I do not have adequate reputation to edit the post.

Comment: My comment was more in response to HamZa's comment. @jaytea since you don't have edit privileges, you can suggest edits and editor restrictions are in place and these restrictions will not come into play when users with edit privilege are editing

Comment: Otherwise I do agree that showing this message seems odd here

Comment: SO/SE performs checks on the current state of the text in the editor. The checks must pass in order to not get that notification and various others. The checks don't test just the changes you are making, but the entire current text. Such checks change over time and by privilege level (reputation). Thus, you can encounter questions where it's not possible to save the unchanged text, even if you have full editing privileges (>2k rep). An example of such is when a site is blacklisted. You can't save an edit to a post which contains the blacklisted site without removing the site from the post.

Comment: @Makyen This is certainly good information, but is it useful? I don't see how it's possible to reconcile the error message I see with the fact that HamZa is able to edit the post with unchanged text and I am not. Do you not agree that this is evidence of a bug?

Comment: @jaytea, It's unclear if it's a bug, feature, or misfeature. Note that the fact that the question is locked is also a factor, as it's not possible to edit the answer at all for users with very low reputation (e.g. 21). When I attempted to edit the *answer* with the account I use for low-rep testing, it produced the error: "Question is locked.", and did not even show the edit interface.

Comment: @Makyen So it is possible that one of StackOverflow's features is to report erroneous error messages to its users?

Comment: @jaytea Without knowing what it's detecting/reporting in more detail, it's not possible to say if it's a bug, or a poorly designed exception notice which doesn't tell the user enough information to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @jaytea The two can be reconciled if you assume that the "poorly-formatted-code" filter has a rep limit. HamZa has high rep, so could potentially be exempt from such a filter.

Comment: @mbrig Indeed that makes sense and seems to me to be the most likely scenario.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60676356/5472354 I cannot edit it unless I remove the quote. Why is that? Does it also have to do with reputation?