# Why is this regex question locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-posts

I don't think I've ever seen a "locked" question? Why is this locked?

[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/4561887)

Additionally, I'd like it unlocked. Any way to unlock it?

Comment: [What is a locked post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)

Comment: I can venture a guess that it is to stop the post from receiving an answer per programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has been a while since I locked the question. I think the main reason was that it was not tagged with a language tag, but instead of closing it as "too broad", I understood the need for such [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) [reference questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate), and decided to wiki-lock it instead to encourage others to improve the top answer.

It kinda worked, since there are [144 linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2973436?sort=newest) to it at the moment.

Now, I notice this question has not been added to the [main regex wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) yet, and it probably could benefit from being added to it.

Comment: Would you  be willing to unlock it? Among other things, that would allow upvoting the question and adding comments to link it to other posts.

Comment: The top answer to that question is pretty lacking. The second answer does a way better job at explaining what zero-width expressions can actually be used for, while the first gives pretty nonsensical examples (e.g. `A(?=B)` is useless and should always be written as `AB` or `(A)B`).

Comment: I strongly disagree @l4mpi.  There are certainly appropriate times when `A(?=B)` is more appropriate versus those alternatives.

Comment: @mickmackusa then please extend the top answer of that question with any such example or elaborate why it would be useful. Note I'm aware that it can be useful for more generalized expressions such as `XA(?=B)Y` for any given X and Y, but that's not what's explained by the answer. Otherwise, the only difference I'm aware of is the grouping, which obviously can be resolved without zero-width expressions.

Comment: @l4mpi trivial example: `echo AB | grep -Po 'A(?=B)'` from which is easy to come up with actually useful scenarios - any case when you want to `grep` for something that matters followed by some other pattern that's not relevant for further processing. Of course there are other ways not using lookaheads or `\K` for this, but this expresses the *intent* most directly.

Comment: @muru that's still about grouping though. Point taken that in situations like `grep -o` you don't have direct control about the group selection and then it does make a difference. But IMO that's still a niche case compared to using regex in your own code, for which I don't see any value in the examples given in the fist answer.

Answer (score 16):

Posts like this are locked as a community wiki/collaborative effort when they receive an excessive number of answers whose content largely overlaps. Instead of providing new answers, it's better for users to focus on improving the existing answer(s) (ideally the top answer) if they have new information to add.

In this case, the moderator who locked the question probably felt the existing answer does a far better job at comprehensively answering it than multiple fragmented answers would (keep in mind that is exactly the ideal model for asking & answering on Stack Overflow: where the best answer rises to the top and continues to get edited with new information as time goes on, and other, old answers are discarded).

It is unlikely that you will get the question unlocked given that it has been locked for 4 years and it's clear from the answer's history that other users have no difficulty with providing edits to improve it. At the very least, I expect you would need to provide some evidence here to back up your request for unlocking it (moderators don't unlock questions just because someone asks--there needs to be a compelling reason).

Comment: In addition to this, it's worth noting that our lock system is somewhat rudimentary. Other than comment locks, lock types generally shut down questions far more than appropriate, including preventing voting, editing and commenting on the answer when, in this case, all that was likely wanted was preventing new answers.

Comment: @Catija, if someone wanted to simply prevent new answers, shouldn't they simply close the question instead of locking it? Locking seems much more restrictive--and rare.

Comment: @GabrielStaples No - they're two completely different features. Closed questions indicate that the question is somehow a bad fit for the site - it's out of scope or off topic or unclear. That doesn't seem to align with the question you've linked to at all. It's a good question, mods just wanted to prevent it ending up with dozens of near-identical answers.

Comment: @Catija Granted, OP did not state _why_ they want the question unlocked, but I have to assume it was so that they could provide an answer (which an answer-only lock would still prevent). I'm sure the mods would agree that it would be great to have the lock options revamped/overhauled though :-)